# loops within a function

Tags: function, loops, python-3.x

why isn't computer becoming x ? after it goes through  the loop and finds something that is in list and not in picked shouldn't it assign that value of x to computer ?

```
def ComputerMove(gameboard):
    for x in list:
        if x not in picked and x in list:
            computer = x 



list =  ("b2", "a1", "c3", "a3", "c1", "a2", "b3", "b1", "c2")

gameboard = {0:' ', 1:' ', 2:' ',
         3:' ', 4:' ', 5:' ',
         6:' ', 7:' ', 8:' ',
         }
picked = ("b2", "a1", "c3", "a3")
ComputerMove(gameboard)
```

Comment: What should ComputerMove return/do?

Comment: that's just calling the function back, so it can actually run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `list` is a type/reseved so you cannot use it as variable name. Second, what you have is a tuple, not a list. So, I converted those and this code seems to work:

```
def ComputerMove(gameboard):
    for x in l:
        if x not in picked:
            computer = x
            return computer # not sure what do you want to do with this value?



l =  ["b2", "a1", "c3", "a3", "c1", "a2", "b3", "b1", "c2"]

gameboard = {0:' ', 1:' ', 2:' ',
         3:' ', 4:' ', 5:' ',
         6:' ', 7:' ', 8:' ',
         }
picked = ["b2", "a1", "c3", "a3"]
ComputerMove(gameboard) 
>>c1
```

Comment: You *can* use reserved keywords as variable names, but it is not recommended.

Comment: @SteinarLima IMO that's beyond not recommended. Overwriting types and keywords is the biggest no-no in Python which is why I often tell novices that's not allowed. Just because the interpreter will let you doesn't mean it's good. For instance in Py 2.x you _can_ do True, False = False, True would anyone in their sane mind do that? =)